# Koltin inner class extends inner class in outer class with parallel hierarchies but give Unhandled JavaScript exception

Tags: kotlin, generics, constructor, inner-classes

```
class QualifiedCalls {
  var name = "QualifiedCalls"

  open inner class Outer1 {
    open var name = "Outer1"

    open inner class Inner1 {
      open var name = "Inner1"
      var superResult: String

      constructor() {
        this.superResult = this.name + this@Outer1.name + this@QualifiedCalls.name
      }
    }
  }

    inner class Outer2 : Outer1() {
    override var name = "Outer2"

    inner class Inner2 : Inner1 {
      override var name = "Inner2"
      var result: String 

      constructor() : super() {
          

        result = this@Outer2.name + this@QualifiedCalls.name + superResult
      }
    }
  }
}

fun main() {
    val test = QualifiedCalls().Outer2().Inner2()
  // In java test.result is "Inner2Outer2QualifiedCallsInner1Outer1QualifiedCalls"
    println(test.result)
}
```

I expected this to print "Inner2Outer2QualifiedCallsInner1Outer1QualifiedCalls", however, it gives the following error

```
Unhandled JavaScript exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') 
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at QualifiedCalls$Outer1$QualifiedCalls$Outer1$Inner1_init (eval at  (https://play.kotlinlang.org/main.js:2:2074837), :51:66)
    at QualifiedCalls$Outer2$QualifiedCalls$Outer2$Inner2_init (eval at  (https://play.kotlinlang.org/main.js:2:2074837), :94:5)
```

If I write like following:

```
inner class Outer2 : Outer1() {
    override var name = "Outer2"

    inner class Inner2() : Inner1() {
      override var name = "Inner2"
      var result: String

      init {
          

        result = this@Outer2.name + this@QualifiedCalls.name + superResult
      }
    }
  }
```

Then the test result will be `Outer2QualifiedCallsundefinedOuter2QualifiedCalls`, why the result is this? From my understanding `Code in initializer blocks effectively becomes part of the primary constructor. Delegation to the primary constructor happens as the first statement of a secondary constructor, so the code in all initializer blocks and property initializers is executed before the body of the secondary constructor.` Thanks

Comment: playground https://pl.kotl.in/7i2OaAqey and https://pl.kotl.in/auyBIjuX5

Comment: Most likely a compiler bug. There have been similar issues [like this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22169/Reference-to-outer-class-instance-wrongly-passes-to-a-super-ctor-in-the-case-when-both-are-secondary-ctor).